# Silence Android Phone in Java

Tags: java, android, silent

How can I silence the android phone in java? A code sample is VERY helpful.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the [`AudioManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) class.

In this class you're looking for `setRingerMode()` function.

```
AudioManager audiomanage = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audiomanage.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

The values you can pass into the function are:

> The ringer mode, one of `RINGER_MODE_NORMAL`, `RINGER_MODE_SILENT`, 
>   or `RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE`.

You have to add this into the manifest file:

```
android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS
```

Comment: Is there something aditional to this that must be done? I have pretty much this exact same code (including the permission) but I always get an exception when trying to get the SystemService.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `AudioManager` class's methods to silence audio.

For instance, to turn off the ringer use `manager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT)`

You can get an instance of the `AudioManager` by calling `Context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE)`

---

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setRingerMode(int)