# Silence phone from within a Service (not main thread)

Tags: android

I was just looking at this example:

[Silence Android Phone in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738724/silence-android-phone-in-java)

Can you silence a phone from within a Service running in the background, or do you need to pass a message to the Activity so that it can silence the phone?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If what I posted as an answer has answered your main question, please consider marking it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Service extends Context, so you do not have to use an Activity.

This is due to how Java works. For information on inheritance, see [here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/inheritance.html)

For the Service API, see [here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

Comment: cool thanks, im getting some error in my code...Unable to instantiate service com.example.reminderalarm.AlarmService: java.lang.NullPointerException and it only seems to pop up when i start using the AudioManager, without that the Service gets instantiated fine and runs away grand, any ideas why that would be?

Comment: I'd make a new question and post all your relevant code **and** logcat. It's better than having two separate questions in one post.