# Auto Silent android device with timer set my user

Tags: java, android

I have 2 buttons in my app
starttime and endtime

Now I want the device to turn in silent mode during the start and end time duration set by the user.....how can I do this?

My code for taking input for starttime and endtime 
    **`mainactivity.java code`** 
    package com.example.h.manualsilent;

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TimePickerDialog tpd;
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat;
String time;
Button sttime;
Button entime;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sttime=(Button)findViewById(R.id.startbtn);
    entime=(Button)findViewById(R.id.endbtn);
}
public void starttime(View view){
    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
    int hour=cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    int minute=cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    //int inst=cal.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
    tpd=new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new 
    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

        @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    Time time = new Time(hourOfDay, minute,0);

            //little h uses 12 hour format and big H uses 24 hour format
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");

            //format takes in a Date, and Time is a sublcass of Date
            String s = simpleDateFormat.format(time);
            sttime.setText(s);
        }
    },hour,minute,false);
    tpd.show();
    }
    public void endtime(View view){
    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour=cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    int minute=cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    //int inst=cal.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
    tpd=new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new 
    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        Time time = new Time(hourOfDay, minute,0);

            //little h uses 12 hour format and big H uses 24 hour format
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");

            //format takes in a Date, and Time is a sublcass of Date
            String s = simpleDateFormat.format(time);
            entime.setText(s);
        }
        },hour,minute,false);
        tpd.show();
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`AudioManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) for changing from genral mode to silent mode.

#### Code:

```
AudioManager audioManager;
audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
// changing to silent mode
audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

You have to give the required permission also in `manifest` file.

```
android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS
```

You can use the above code to set the phone to silent based on the condition that you need.

You can also change back to VIBRATE or GENERAL using [`AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE) or [`AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#RINGER_MODE_NORMAL) respectively.

Comment: ok now I know how to toggle between silent and general mode...this is helpful....but how can I keep tracking the duration set by user and activate silent or general mode....I have edited my question...can you help @Johny

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `AudioManager` class.

In this class you're looking for `setRingerMode()` function.

```
AudioManager audiomanage = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audiomanage.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

The values you can pass into the function are:

> The ringer mode, one of `RINGER_MODE_NORMAL`, `RINGER_MODE_SILENT`, or
>   `RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE`.

You have to add this into the manifest file:

```
android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS
```

*I saw this here -* https://stackoverflow.com/a/3738768/8214839