# Why android removes supporting for silenseRinger() when there is an incoming call?

Tags: android

I want to silence the ring when there is an incoming call, and I setup a button to do a test like this:

```java
silenceButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ITelephony iTelephony = getITelephony();
        try {
            iTelephony.silenceRinger();
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

but the ring is not silenced when I click the button and the logcat outputs an error:

```
PhoneInterfaceManager: silenseRinger not supported
```

I think my `getITelephony()` is working correctly because I can decline the incoming call based on it:

```java
declineButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ITelephony iTelephony = getITelephony();
        try {
            iTelephony.endCall();
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

So why android stops supporting for silence the incoming call? Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would look something like this:

> android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
//silent mode
audioManager.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER, AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_OFF);
audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

Read these other questions for more info:

- [Silence Android Phone in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738724/silence-android-phone-in-java)
- [Auto Silent android device with timer set my user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45658491/auto-silent-android-device-with-timer-set-my-user)
- [Android - make phone silent for a limited amounts of time (dyanmically)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50033851/android-make-phone-silent-for-a-limited-amounts-of-time-dyanmically)
- [When I set the ringermode to RINGER_MODE_SILENT, the phone still vibrates and the icon in the menu is set to the 'vibrate' icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26606941/when-i-set-the-ringermode-to-ringer-mode-silent-the-phone-still-vibrates-and-th)

Comment: Thanks for your code, that works! by the way, do you know why the android system won't support silenseRinger() method which is more convenient?

Comment: I'm not sure, the docs didn't state why it was removed. BTW please mark this answer correct if it solved your issue. Thanks!